# MongoDB - how to use $ifNull only on a field that exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using `$lookup`, which may or may not return something. But if it does, i need to check the looked up value and check a specific field to see if it is null, and if it is, set it to something.

I tried this:

```
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: 
            "item_templates",
        localField:
            "based_on",
        foreignField:
            "_id",
        as:
            "template"
    }
},
{
    $addFields:
    {
        "template.image.url":
        {
            $ifNull:
            [
                "$template.image.url",
                "http://via.placeholder.com/400x700/d3d3d3/000000/?text=No%20Image&"                                        
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

but it seems to have no effect on `template.image.url` (which is an array of objects), it actually returns an array instead, with one element as `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use newer `$lookup` syntax to achieve the expected result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "item_templates",
    "let": { "based_on": "$based_on" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$based_on"] }}},
      { "$addFields": {
        "image.url": {
          "$ifNull": [
            "$image.url",
            "http://via.placeholder.com/400x700/d3d3d3/000000/?text=No%20Image&"
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "template"
  }}
])
```

Comment: great answers as always.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$project`.

```
{
   $unwind:{
       path: "$template",
       includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
       preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
   }
},
{
   $project:{
     template.image.url: { 
        $ifNull: [ 
             "$template.image.url", 
              "http://via.placeholder.com/400x700/d3d3d3/000000/?text=No%20Image&" 
       ]
      },
   }
}
```

Comment: still turns it into an array with one element as `null`. Also, the project gets rid of all the other fields, which is undesirable.

Comment: Before $project unwind `template` also.